# Adding different color while editting text in UITextView irrespective of cursor position in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a textview where I pre populate it with some required comments for eg: "Hi this is John" would show up in textview with blue color. Now what I need is, whatever new editing is done in textview it would come up in black. So, if I edit the text to "Hi this is Steve". Only "Steve" should be in black and rest should be in blue. I know I will have to use `NSAttributedString`, but how do I go about it?

Right now I do this on my view load

```
descriptionTextView.text = myString
descriptionTextView.textColor = UIColor.blue
```

And this on texteditting

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    descriptionTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
}
```

But this will change everything to black. Any ideas?

Comment: NSAttributedString has append method you need to use that to add more text and specify color.

Comment: How I do it, just catch the new edited text and find the range of the edited text in the complete string and append the attributes on the edited text range in `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Guys, finding range and coloring text is fine, but where would I do that? If I make that change in textview change or shouldchange method, as soon as I type any text my cursor would go in the  end.  I won't be able to edit pointing my cursor somewhere else.

Comment: @Gamerlegend Just to clarify me, you need a diferent color for any text added until the `didEndEditing` method is called?

Comment: Yes, and it should be irrespective of cursor change. Most close I got is to using textView.typingAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] but the problem with that is if I start editing between blue fonts first character would be always blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `UITextViewDelegate`

Set delegate for `UITextView` and make a global variable of `NSRange` as:

```
IBOutlet UITextView *textVw;
NSRange textRange;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor]; // set initial needed color
    NSString *string = @"Hi this is John"; // set initial string to color
    NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color };
    NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attrs];
    textVw.attributedText = attrStr;

    //Set delegate of UITextView
    [textVw setDelegate:self];
}

#pragma UITextViewDelegate Methods.
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
     //Check string is written or backspace (with prediction on).
     if (text.length > 1) {

         //Make Range for black text in textview.
         textRange = NSMakeRange(range.location, text.length + 1);

         return YES;
     }

     //Check string is written or backspace.
     if (text.length > 0 && ![text isEqualToString:@" "]) {

         //Make Range for black text in textview.
         textRange = NSMakeRange(range.location, 1);

        return YES;
     }

    return YES;
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    //Check there are some value is written or not.
    if (textRange.length > 0) {

        //Check textview is rest with initial value or not.
        if ([textVw.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Hi this is John"] == NSOrderedSame) {

            //Rest value so make string as blue.
            UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor]; // set initial needed color
            NSString *string = @"Hi this is John"; // set initial string to color
            NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color };
            NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attrs];
            textVw.attributedText = attrStr;

        } else {

            NSMutableAttributedString *text =
            [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
             initWithAttributedString: textVw.attributedText];

            [text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor blackColor]
                         range:textRange];

            //Add new Attributed value to textView with black color.
            [textVw setAttributedText: text];

        }

        //After assign value to textfiled make textRange varibale as default value for safe handler.
        textRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
      //Check there are some value is written or not.

      if (textRange.length > 1) {
             //For maintain cursor position with prediction on.
             [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(textRange.location + textRange.length , 0)];

      } else if (textRange.length > 0) {
            //For maintain cursor position.
            [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(textRange.location + 1, 0)];
      }
}
```

Comment: This automatically transfers my cursor to end when I start editing between blue text.

Comment: @Gamerlegend please check updated answer for maintain cursor position
I am just added textViewDidChangeSelection delegate method.

Comment: hey buddy, there's a small bug in this, ie, when you select prediction word from keyboard, the cursor doesn't goes to the end, instead it leaves a space from first character and stays there. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Gamerlegend please check updated answer for maintain prediction on cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

class AViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textView.delegate = self;
    textView.text = ""
    textView.textColor = UIColor.blue
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {


    let colorAttr = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: colorAttr)

    let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()

    combination.append(textView.attributedText!)
    combination.append(attributedString)
    textView.attributedText = combination

    return true

}
```

Basically `shouldChangeTextIn` is always called when new character is tapped. Using `NSMutableAttributedString` you can easily append old `attributedString` with black color with newly string.

PS : You neeed to conform to `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.

Comment: I'm using textview, also this would fail if I change my cursor to any other point

Comment: Answer updated. Now it's using UITextView.
You're right, this answer dosent work when you move the cursor, only append the new text to the end.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the main problem, I need it to be able to work even if user changes the cursor to somewhere else.

Comment: please edit your question. You didnt mention the cursor change.